# How to modify the auto generated media3 notification ? (java)

Tags: java, notifications, exoplayer

I build an exoplayer with Media3 1.0.0-rc01 with a mediasession service, like describe in [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/session/mediasessionservice)

It's generated a media notification automatically and i want to change colors (text, background) and icon (and more).

The guide says : "To provide a custom notification, create a MediaNotification.Provider with DefaultMediaNotificationProvider.Builder or by creating a custom implementation of the provider interface. Add your provider to your MediaSession with setMediaNotificationProvider."

So i created a new class for the provider :

```
package myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi;
import androidx.media3.session.CommandButton;
import androidx.media3.session.DefaultMediaNotificationProvider;
import androidx.media3.session.MediaNotification;
import androidx.media3.session.MediaSession;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

@UnstableApi
public class MyMediaNotificationProvider implements MediaNotification.Provider {

    private Context context;
    public MyMediaNotificationProvider(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MediaNotification createNotification(
            MediaSession mediaSession,
            ImmutableList<CommandButton> customLayout,
            MediaNotification.ActionFactory actionFactory,
            Callback onNotificationChangedCallback) {

        // Create the notification
        return new DefaultMediaNotificationProvider(context).createNotification(
                mediaSession,
                customLayout,
                actionFactory,
                onNotificationChangedCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleCustomCommand(
            MediaSession session,
            String action,
            Bundle extras) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And I added the `setMediaNotificationProvider(new MyMediaNotificationProvider());` in my PlaybackService class, to call the new created class above :

```
package myapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import androidx.media3.common.MediaItem;
import androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi;
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayer;
import androidx.media3.session.MediaSession;
import androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService;

@UnstableApi public class PlaybackService extends MediaSessionService {
    private MediaSession mediaSession = null;

    @Override
    public MediaSession onGetSession(MediaSession.ControllerInfo controllerInfo) {
        // If desired, validate the controller before returning the media session
        return mediaSession;
    }

    // Create your Player and MediaSession in the onCreate lifecycle event
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Create the player and the mediasession
        ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        mediaSession = new MediaSession.Builder(this, player).build();

        // Build the media item.
        Uri mp3 = Uri.parse("android.resource://myapp/raw/mysoundtoplay");
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(mp3);
        // Set the media item to be played.
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        // loop mode
        player.setRepeatMode(player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
        // Prepare the player.
        player.prepare();
        // Play
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        // CALL MY NEW CLASS TO CREATE NOTIFICATION
        Context context = getApplicationContext(); // context must be passed to class
        setMediaNotificationProvider(new MyMediaNotificationProvider(context));

    }

    // Remember to release the player and media session in onDestroy
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mediaSession.getPlayer().release();
        mediaSession.release();
        mediaSession = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

The app is doing fine (sound is playing) and the notification is visible

The [androidx migration guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3/getting-started/migration-guide) says "An app can customize the notification by setting a custom MediaNotification.Provider in onCreate() that replaces the DefaultMediaNotificationProvider. The MediaLibraryService then takes care of starting the service in the foreground as required.
By overriding MediaLibraryService.updateNotification() an app can further take full ownership of posting a notification and starting/stopping the service in the foreground as required."

Anyone can help me customizing the notification (text, color, icon...) ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass real context, for example to the constructor: public MyMediaNotificationProvider(Context context){ this.context = context; }

Comment: Thank you "sdex", now the notification is visible. I've updated my question with new code. The problem of displaying the notification is solved, but the question about customizing the notification is still on going.

Answer (score 4):

First thing, media3 v1.1.1 was made available August 16, 2023.

To set the notification icon, adjust your `DefaultMediaNotificationProvider` in `MyMediaNotificationProvider#createNotification()` to the following:

```
            // Create the notification
            DefaultMediaNotificationProvider defaultMediaNotificationProvider = new DefaultMediaNotificationProvider(mContext);
            defaultMediaNotificationProvider.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.blb_reverse_icon);
            MediaNotification mediaNotification = defaultMediaNotificationProvider
                    .createNotification(
                            mediaSession,
                            customLayout,
                            actionFactory,
                            onNotificationChangedCallback);

            return mediaNotification;
```

To set titles and background, you will need to set metadata on your `MediaItem`(s) using `setMediaMetadata()`.

```
    Uri artworkUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+mActivity.getPackageName()+"/"+R.drawable.mediasession_bg_artwork);
    Uri mp3 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+mActivity.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.myMedia.mp3);
    MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
            .setMediaMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder()
                    .setTitle("My Title")
                    .setArtist("My Artist")
                    .setArtworkUri(artworkUri)
                    .build()
            )
            .setUri(mp3)
            .build();
```

You can find more information on MediaItem metadata [Media3 MediaMetadata.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/common/MediaMetadata.Builder)

The trick for the background is in the `.setArtworkUri()`.

Comment: Thanks @Dan
Customizing the notification icon works with defaultMediaNotificationProvider.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.blb_reverse_icon);
But I haven't managed to customize artwork with.setArtworkUri(artworkUri) and it is always the artwork from the mp3 that is shown (a tried to copy a backgroup.jpg file in drawable folder and set filename, and also tried existing drawable in android and tried R.color.black). The problem is also that setArtworkUri() may custom artwork but i'm not sure it custom the automatic backgroud color of the notification (based on artwork)

Comment: @user924 It is the OP's implementation of MediaNotification.Provider in the question.